Build solution file using batch commands on Git repository
Our is .Net project and we are planning jenkins pipeline to copy dlls from deploy folder.
We need to create batch file  which should clean and build solution and copy dlls to deploy folder on git.
Our Git structure contains 'mainrepo' which has 3 repos and each repo has couple of projects.
In one repo we have .Net solution which has mapping for all the projects in all repos.
Here is  structure
mainrepo
   repo1->proj1 ,proj2
   repo2--> proj3,solution file (.sln)
   repo3-> proj4,proj5
   deployfolder
   batchfile.bat

Here is our requirement. We need to build solution and copy dlls from each project folder in each repo to deploy folder.
Lets say for example
repo1->Proj1->Build folder dlls.
repo1->Proj2->Build folder dlls.
repo2->Proj3->Build folder dlls.
repo3->Proj4->Build folder dlls.

When i run batch file command
%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe %SRC_DIR%\Solution.sln  /t:Build  /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU

It will build solution and all the projects in solution (Proj1,Proj2,Proj3,Proj4) have dlls in corresponding project bin\Release folders.
As prerequisite, i need to first delete bin and obj folders in all project folder directories.
Iam not sure if below command works and which dir will it refer.
command:
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /ad obj') do if exist %%x rd /s /q "%%x"

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /ad bin') do if exist %%x rd /s /q "%%x"

Expectation:
should remove bins and obj folders in all project folders(proj1,proj2,proj3) in all repos(repo1,repo2,repo3)
here is batch file script I am planning but not sure if this works across multiple repos
Batch script:
set SRC_DIR=%CD%  :: is this targets to mainrepo
set SRC_Deploy_DIR=%CD%\deployfolder

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /ad obj') do if exist %%x rd /s /q "%%x"

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /s /b /ad bin') do if exist %%x rd /s /q "%%x"

%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe %SRC_DIR%\repo2\folder2\Solution.sln   /t:Clean /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU

%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe %SRC_DIR%\repo2\folder2\Solution.sln  /t:Build  /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU

 ::@echo copy dlls from build folder in coresponding project folder to mainrepo->deployfolder
 
 SET REPO1_SRC_DIR=%CD%\repo1
 
 :: to go through all folders in repo1 and copy dlls from all project folders to deploy directory
 CD %REPO1_SRC_DIR%
FOR %%i IN ( *.dll*  ) DO (
    COPY /Y %REPO1_SRC_DIR%\%%i %SRC_Deploy_DIR%\%%i
)

Please let me know if batch script works fine and it can loop through all repos.
Batch file stays under main repo.

Add the following line above everything in the batch file shown, CD /D "%~dp0." 2>NUL || Exit /B.

Instead of mixing batch and MSBuild, consider that all of the work of cleaning and copying can be performed in MSBuild. You can have a very simple batch file that simply runs MSBuild.

Why are you hard-coding the path to an ancient version of MSBuild? Is your project .NET or .NET Framework? Do you have the .NET SDK installed and/or "Build Tools for Visual Studio"? If your project is .NET and the .NET SDK is installed, use the dotnet CLI tool. If your project is .Net Framework (or you are mixing .NET and .Net Framework projects), install "Build Tools", have your batch file call VsDevCmd.bat (to modify the PATH to include the VS tools), and run MSBuild (which will use the VS tools version).

You could use msbuild's /p:outputdir=... to build to a desired directory.
